# Parse Variables Using DCG

Tags: prolog, grammar, dcg

I am having trouble parsing sequences that begin with capital letters into variables using Prolog's DCG notation. For instance, if I have the string

```
f a X y Z X
```

and a DCG that parses this string, is there any way to parse each capitalized letter into a unique Prolog variable. E.g., parse `Y` to a variable and each `X` to a variable? The intended application would be to build the functor

```
T = f(a,X,y,Z,X)
```

via a DCG rule ending with the statement

```
{T =.. [Head|Args]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for `term_to_atom/3`:

```
?- term_to_atom(Term, 'f(a,X,y,Z,X)').
Term = f(a, _G304, y, _G306, _G304).
```

Comment: This is precisely the predicate I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using capital letters as an atom, you have to surround them between single quotes. E.g. 'X' and 'Z'.

Otherwise, they will be considered as prolog variables.